# ConvertRecord processor issue with XML to JSON conversion Apache Nifi

Tags: json, xml, format, apache-nifi

I have a requirement where I am converting data from an API to JSON format. The output of the API is initially in XML, so I am using XMLReader controller service to read the XML data, and JSONRecordSetWriter controller service to convert it to JSON format in Apache Nifi 1.9.2.

When I use ConvertRecord processor with the same controller services, my output merely shows the avro schema and not the data expected. I have tried out many options like using AvroSchemaRegistry controller service, but only the schema is seen and null values are passed. Can anyone explain this behavior?

**XML flowfile output:**

```
<field1 value="AAAA"/>
   <field2 value="BBBB"/>
   <field3 value="male"/>
```

**JSON output:**

```
[ {
  "field1" : null,
  "field2" : null,
  "field3" : null
} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation specifies that "Records are expected in the second level of XML data, embedded in an enclosing root tag." Your input file appears to be a list of XML tags with no root tag enclosing them.

You could use ReplaceText to wrap the XML in a root tag, then the XMLReader should parse the fields as expected.

Comment: Can you please explain how this can be done with the processor configuration steps? And my XML appears to have a root tag in my system.

Comment: Can you share a sample input XML file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Patient xmlns="value1">
       <birthDate value="value2"/>
       <active value="true"/>
       <gender value="male"/>
       <deceasedBoolean value="false"/>
       <id value="dummy value"/>
       <careProvider>
          <display value="value3"/>
          <reference value="value4"/>
       </careProvider>
 </Patient>

Comment: This is the sample piece of XML data - apologies but I am unable to indent the content.